# No funciona (change) en ng-select2

Tags: angular, select2, angular8

Muy buenos días.
Estuve tratando de usar la librería ng-select2 para Angular 8, a fin de poder autocompletar un campo que posee muchas opciones. Las opciones del campo siguiente del formulario, dependerán de lo que hayamos elegido en el primero. Lo tengo realizado con funciones que, en un etiquetado convencional funciona perfecto.

```
     <select name="modelo" #modelo="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="modeloSelected" class="form-control" (change)="traerLotes(modeloSelected)" required>
          <option *ngFor="let option of options_modelos">
            {{option}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

Solo que el autocompletar es el básico de html, (no filtras mientras tipeas, y debes hacerlo muy rápido para que encuentre la opción buscada) Al querer implementar ng-select2, (solo lo necesito en este primer campo) no logro hacer que dispare la función al elegir la opción.

```
    <ng-select2 name="modelo" [(ngModel)]="modeloSelected" [data]="options_modelos" [placeholder]="'Modelo...'" [width]="250" (change)=traerLotes(modeloSelected)">
```

Probé con el evento (click), pero funciona con un clic de retraso. (No se si se entiende)
Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.
Saludos y que tengan un buen día.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias librerías con nombres similares, pero si te refieres a [ésta](https://github.com/tealpartners/ng-select2#readme), en lugar de `change` tienes que usar `valueChanged`:

```
<ng-select2 name="modelo" [(ngModel)]="modeloSelected" [data]="options_modelos" 
   [placeholder]="'Modelo...'" [width]="250" (valueChanged)=traerLotes(modeloSelected)">
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Pablo. Eso es lo que estaba buscando.Saludos!!